# Border-radius CSS property curve outside

Tags: css

How to make the border radius curve outside ?

[image]

The bottom side the border radius want to curve outside. How to do it with CSS3 ?

Comment: This won't be possible without additional markup since parts of the graphic are outside the box model.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without any extra mark up. Write like this:

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 30px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.active:after,
.active:before {
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  border-top: 0;
}

.active:after {
  border-left: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  left: -41px;
}

.active:before {
  border-right: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  right: -41px;
}
```

```html
<div class="active">hi</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/p6sGJ/

Comment: You forgot to add the "real" `border-radius` property. We don't want any more of this crazyness: http://remysharp.com/2012/02/09/vendor-prefixes-about-to-go-south/

Comment: That's nice but just i give an example which support -webkit & mozilla browsers :)

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that someone's probably going to just copy paste your code, and that's probably how the issue started in the first place. So I just did a quick edit on your answer, which is a good solution, by the way, so we can try to avoid this as much as possible.